# Ruby on Rails and CruiseControl.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, notifications, cruisecontrol.rb

How do I set up the email notification with CruiseControl.rb? I've specified the ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings in the site-config.rb but where do I specify who will receive the email notification? Do I need to create a config.xml file? If so, where do I put the file and do you have an example of the contents of this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually specified in the project specific cruise_config.rb file.

This is actually created for you in each ~/.cruise/projects/ directory.

An example one looks like this :

```
Project.configure do |project|
  project.email_notifier.emails = ["you@example.com"]
end
```

Comment: I was putting the cruise_config.rb in the cruise folder instead of the projects folder. That's why it didn't work before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look in config/site_config.rb. There is a commented out template for enabling email notification.

Comment: I've already uncommented out the smtp settings in config/site_config.rb but where do I specify the To: address?